# How would you visually represent 1 billion events on a single dashboard

Tags: database, bigdata

How would you visually represent 1 billion events on a single dashboard in Big Data

Answer (score 0):

This is a really broad question. It would be difficult to find a useful way to visualize that volume of data such that a user could interact with it. You would need to break it down into categories of events, and allow the user to drill down into those categories until the subset of that data was small enough that you could realistically display the events themselves.

When dealing with numbers in the billions, you could either display actual numbers, or use pictograms to represent sub-units of the large numbers, perhaps a single graphic/image for each million, divided into categories with a scale.